# Expectation for a bivariate variable distribution

Tags: probability

> Flip a fair coin three times. Let X be the number of tails in the first flip and Y be the total number of tails observed.

Find $E( XY ).$
The approach i followed was to calculate individual expectations of X and Y which came out to be 0.5 and 1.5 respectively but am unable to proceed post that.
I tried to make joint pmf of it but did not find a way to calculate the above.

Comment: $Y-X$ and $X$ are independent.

Comment: @Yuta Y-X are events with tail not observed in first flip?

Comment: $Y-X$ is the number of tails in the 2nd and 3rd flips

Comment: Thanks I am getting expectation of y-x as 9/4 is it correct?

Comment: Got it thanks sorry my bad the expected value for my will come out approximately to 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since only flip three times, nothing is preventing you from writing out all outcomes along with probability and compute the weighted sum.